# Galaxy S3 Video Recording via API "rolls" or is corrupted in Bright Light

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy

Following the instructions from Google here exactly as it is (QUALITY_HIGH):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

When doing this with a Galaxy S3 (US Version) everything seems fine in indoor lighting.  But when the camera goes outside and it is bright (maybe it needs to increase the shutter speed) something strange happens.  The video starts "rolling" like a bad TV signal, and the image gets to be very low quality.   It almost seems like the image sensor got overloaded and messed up.

I tried recording with the normal camera application and it seems to have no problems under the same condition.  But using the API as described here generates this problem.  Since the S3 is pretty popular -- anyone run into this problem before?

Is there some kind of hidden setting that the main camera app uses for camera setup?  I tried flattening the camera settings to take a look at what's in there and there are tons of settings but i dont know what they all do without documentation.  already tried turning off anti-banding and luma-adaptation and that didnt seem to do anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Need more testing but this seems to do it.    There is a hidden setting called "camera-mode" that is normally set to -1.  I changed it to a 1 and suddenly it is fine and functioning like the normal camera app..   anyone know what this mode thing actually means?

Camera.Parameters lParam = prCamera.getParameters();
lParam.set("camera-mode",1); 
prCamera.setParameters(lParam);

Is what did the trick if anyone else seems to run into the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Need more testing but this seems to do it.    There is a hidden setting called "camera-mode" that is normally set to -1.  I changed it to a 1 and suddenly it is fine and functioning like the normal camera app..   anyone know what this mode thing actually means?

```
Camera.Parameters lParam = prCamera.getParameters();
lParam.set("camera-mode",1);    
prCamera.setParameters(lParam);
```

Is what did the trick if anyone else seems to run into the problem.\

Comment: On correction.  The parameter to set is "cam_mode".  camera-mode appears to be read only and reflects the status of cam_mode.  It appears the built in camera app sets this to "1" as well.